# Converting an object of class "table" to matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am having a hard time converting from an object of class "table" to a matrix:

I have a categorical variable (a factor in R) and I am using its counts. I have this counts stored in a table:

```
my.table = table(my.dataframef$cat.variable)
class(my.table)
[1] "table"
```

After using this table to do some barplots I want to do a segmented barplot and so I need this information in the form of a matrix. 
This is what I am doing, but it wont work (elements are not in the correct order):

```
my.matrix = matrix(my.table, nrow = n.matrix.rows, ncol = n.matrix.cols)
```

I have solved my problem for a 2x2 matrix by mannually assigning each element to its position:

```
my.matrix = matrix (c(my.table[4],my.table[3],my.table[2],my.table[1]),
        nrow=2,ncol=2)
```

I was wondering if there is an "automatic way" to do this as with bigger matrix it becomes a tough exercise...

Thank you for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: can you provide a `dput` of your matrix?

Comment: Thank you David, this is a dput: `structure(c(686L, 337L, 686L, 466L), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("male(mnt)", "female(mnt)"), c("male(auth)", "female(auth)"
    )))`

Comment: Also, I have realised that indices are in decreasing order. I have tried writing: `my.matrix = matrix (rev(my.table),nrow=2,ncol=2)` and works fine...

Comment: Sorry, I meant a `dput` of your `table` (prior the conversion to matrix)

Comment: Ok, this is it: 
`structure(c(466L, 686L, 337L, 686L), .Dim = 4L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("f-f", "f-m", "m-f", "m-m")), .Names = ""), class = "table")`
Thank you David!

Comment: Put this in the question and then show how your desired output should look like. Also, is there any particular reason you put the elements in this specific order? You could just do something like `matrix(my.table, ncol = length(my.table)/2)`

Comment: what about using `as.matrix(ftable(...))` instead of table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this approach to change the class attribute to "matrix":

```
# input table
tbl <- structure(c(466L, 686L, 337L, 686L), 
      .Dim = 4L,
      .Dimnames = structure(list( c("f-f", "f-m", "m-f", "m-m")),
      .Names = ""), class = "table")


attributes(tbl)$class <- "matrix" 
#alternative syntax: attr(tbl, "class") <- "matrix"
tbl
#f-f f-m m-f m-m 
#466 686 337 686 
#attr(,"class")
#[1] "matrix"
```

Answer (score 13):

Well,  that's not hard if you know that a table is an array with the extra class "table" attached:  You just `unclass()` :

```
> tab <- structure(c(686L, 337L, 686L, 466L), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), 
             .Dimnames = list( c("male(mnt)", "female(mnt)"), 
                               c("male(auth)", "female(auth)" )))
> tab
            male(auth) female(auth)
male(mnt)          686          686
female(mnt)        337          466
> (mat <- unclass(tab))
            male(auth) female(auth)
male(mnt)          686          686
female(mnt)        337          466
> class(mat)
[1] "matrix"
>
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach works for me:

```
tab <- table(sample(LETTERS, 1e4, replace = T), sample(letters, 1e4, replace = T))
class(tab) # table
mat <- matrix(as.numeric(tab), nrow = nrow(tab), ncol = ncol(tab))
class(mat) # matrix
all(mat == tab) # TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> table(letters[1:3], 1:3)

    1 2 3
  a 1 0 0
  b 0 1 0
  c 0 0 1

> class(table(letters[1:3], 1:3))
[1] "table"                                    # is a table

> class(as.matrix(table(letters[1:3], 1:3)))   # still a table
[1] "table"

> as.data.frame(table(letters[1:3], 1:3))      # doesn't work
  Var1 Var2 Freq
1    a    1    1
2    b    1    0
3    c    1    0
4    a    2    0
5    b    2    1
6    c    2    0
7    a    3    0
8    b    3    0
9    c    3    1

> as.data.frame.matrix(table(letters[1:3], 1:3)) # works
  1 2 3
a 1 0 0
b 0 1 0
c 0 0 1

> class(as.matrix(as.data.frame.matrix(table(letters[1:3], 1:3)))) # to your goal
[1] "matrix"
```